# Drug Interactions Web service, Database or JSON/XML Files [For Web Application Development]

Tags: web-apps, database, web-services, xml, json

I would like to know if there is any Web service, database (such as MySQL) or even JSON/XML files [open license] available that can be used to verify drug interactions between two or even a complete list of drugs, i.e. drug-drug interactions.

I pretend to develop a Web application (probably based on RESTful Web services).

Nonetheless, I think that the best solution would probably be through a Web service to keep the data updated.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want an app, then ask here. If you just want the data, then ask on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The FDA maintains an open-access API with drug information - https://open.fda.gov/drug/